# Two questions on single screen

Tags: bug, ios-app

I don't know what's happened but I saw two questions on single screen. One on the main frame and another on the question list:

> [image: 2qs]

- App Version: 1.7.0.1
- Device: Unknown (iPad7,3)
- OS Version: Version 10.3.3 (Build 14G60)